# How do I fix this roof myself?

Tags: roof

It is an almost flat roof.
I don't know what that grey stuff is.
I am looking for a reliable and easy to apply the fix, cost is less of a concern.

By "fix" I mean make it not leak. Don't care about the looks. The roof is invisible from any angle.

[image]

Comment: Define "fixed", please. Should it simply not leak or you wish to get rid of the patchwork and make it look perfect? The grey stuff looks like a generous application of roof cement.

Comment: The grey stuff looks like roofing tar, sold in cans for roof repair.  When using the tar use clothes that are going into the garbage.

Comment: How big is the roof?  How often would you like to go up there and fix it? Every 1 year? 3 years? 5 years? frickin never?